Bonjour scan keeps failing on iOS 18
I am using this Xcode project that should display bonjour devices, it's a little bit old so I realise I have to add permissions in the plist to make it work.
https://github.com/mrmitew/Bonjour-iOS
I added the Permissions:
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_services._dns-sd._udp.</string>
    <string>_tcp.local.</string>
    <string>_http._tcp.</string>
</array>
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the local network to discover services.</string>
<key>com.apple.developer.networking.multicast</key>
<true/>

When I run the app on my iPhone (not simulator) I get:

Discovering.. ["NSNetServicesErrorDomain": 10,
"NSNetServicesErrorCode": -72008] No services were found on the
network

Which is wrong, as my network is riddled with Bonjour devices.
I really just want a list of all bonjour devices, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Is Bonjour traffic being filtered on your network? Some routing setups will drop these mDNS packets outright for security.

if I run the terminal command:
dns-sd -B _services._dns-sd._udp .
I get about 20, so looks like not being filtered.

I have tested some of my code, that works on MacCatalyst (without any permissions)
but does not work on iOS App. Hence the following forums links that provide some info on getting permissions for iOS Apps.
Allow App to find the devices on local network and
Local Network Privacy FAQ and  Using the Multicast Networking Additional Capability. Check to see if your iOS App appears on  Setting->Privacy&security->Local Network

Thanks, it turns out you need to enable some settings on App Store Connect, download a new profile and jump through quite a few hoops. Appreciate the assistance.
